Why did Milosh want to kill himself when he arrive at the red light district?
At the end of episode 49 of Monsters, Milosh wants to kill himself when he arrives at the red light district.
I don't get it. He saw some adults and strippers, and suddenly he believed life was not worth living anymore, I'm confused.
Can someone explain what just happened?

Because he believed that no one needed him anymore. Or rather, because Johan convinced him of this.
Milosh always wanted to find his mother, and believed that they would recognize each other when they met. This became especially important for him after his guardian parent died. Johan sent Milosh to the border, since most street children were the children of prostitutes. At the same time, Johan had previously shaken his confidence that his life was at least somewhat valuable, that he was needed by someone, and that someone would ever love him.
When Milosh came to the neighborhood and saw the people living there, he became depressed, since he believed Johan's words about the meaninglessness and futility of his own life.
